# Solution for IoT web UI

Tags: remote-access

I try to describe my issue with an example.

Just imagine, that I manufacture some device and every device has its own ID and optionally some password. Alice as customer bought my device and established it. And Alice wants to control this device and monitor the state of it. She wants to go to a website, enter the ID and password of the device and get access to it.

I understand the architecture and what I need to provide this functionality. But it's a lot of work. Is there at present any solution that I can use and don't write any code for backend and frontend? I know about such platforms as AWS IoT, but as far as I know it provides messaging platform, but not UI. Seems ThingsBoard.io makes that, but I don't see there possibility to automatically add devices (I need to add every user and device manually in ThingsBoard, if I correctly understood).

Comment: You will able to use thingWorxs for the application. It is very easy to develop the UI which will be accessible through mobile also.

Comment: that scheme would only work with a GSM modem or some other cellular connection, not with wifi.

Comment: Try https://webservice.lk , https://sinric.com

Answer (score 1):

@Uraty try [ubidots](https://help.ubidots.com/articles/654718-controlling-devices-using-mqtt). It provides excellent dashboard which allow you to easily configure your devices and create UI in few mouse clicks. You may also try another simpler service called [Freeboard](http://freeboard.io/) for same purpose.

Comment: Can you add some pros and cons for these?

Comment: @Helmar actually I did not worked much on these platforms as I am designing my own UI using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), [CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/), JavaScript, HTML etc. but I tried ubidots and freeboard, and these are very handy tools. The only disadvantage is that they are paid.

Answer (score -1):

You can use node-red for this. Node-Red gives you a lot of UI based functionalities. There are lot of examples and tutorials to start with.

Comment: Welcome. This seems like it could be a good suggestion; perhaps you could elaborate on how the problem in the OP could be solved with Node-RED? If you have any additional details that you could add, or a link to share to supplement your answer, that'd be great.

Comment: Node-RED is not useful in this situation, the OP is looking for hosted solution that handles collection and visualisation on a per user basis with self/auto enrolling function. Given Node-RED is effectively single user it really does not fit this problem.

Comment: In general, all dashboard offerings fall short sooner or later compared with actual requirements. I speak from experience with ThingWorx and Node-RED. Having said that, we have requirements for which Node-RED suits well and we are planning to roll of a production version soon.